# Inserting A records using the PowerDNS REST api

Tags: powerdns

I have an issue with the web interface. I'm using powerdns v3.4.5 with mysql as the back-end.
I have followed instructions from here:
https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-powerdns-on-ubuntu-14-04/

I have successfully installed powerdns with mysql and got the web-api to work.
However I have trouble inserting A records using the REST api.
I have followed command from here:
https://doc.powerdns.com/md/httpapi/README/

This creates a new zone:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"name":"example.org.", "kind": "Native", "masters": [], "nameservers": ["ns1.example.org.", "ns2.example.org."]}' -v -H 'X-API-Key: changeme' http://127.0.0.1:8081/servers/localhost/zones | jq .
```

(note that I changed the url and removed /api/v1/)

However when I run the following command to add a new A record:

```
curl -X PATCH --data '{"rrsets": [ {"name": "test.example.org.", "type": "A", "ttl": 86400, "changetype": "REPLACE", "records": [ {"content": "192.0.5.4", "disabled": false } ] } ] }' -H 'X-API-Key: changeme' http://127.0.0.1:8081/servers/localhost/zones/example.org. | jq .
```

I get the following error:

"error": "RRset test.example.org. IN A: Name is out of zone"

is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as follows:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"name":"example.org", "kind": "Master","dnssec":false,"soa-edit":"INCEPTION-INCREMENT","masters": [], "nameservers": ["ns1.example.org"]}' -v -H 'X-API-Key: changeme' http://127.0.0.1:8081/servers/localhost/zones | jq .
```

and then:

```
curl -X PATCH --data '{"rrsets": [ {"name": "test.example.org", "type": "A", "changetype": "REPLACE", "records": [ {"content": "192.168.9.9", "disabled": false, "name": "test.example.org", "ttl": 86400, "type": "A", "priority": 0 } ] } ] }' -H 'X-API-Key: changeme' http://127.0.0.1:8081/servers/localhost/zones/example.org | jq .
```

Answer (score 2):

As time passes by, the API changed. The current json structure is a little bit different, also power-dns insists of getting canonical names ending with a dot.

```
# cat example_zone.json
{
    "kind": "Native",
    "masters": [],
    "name": "example.com.",
    "nameservers": [
        "ns1.example.com.",
        "ns2.example.com."
    ]
}

# curl -s -H 'X-API-Key: changeme' --data @example_zone.json  http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v1/servers/localhost/zones

# cat example_rrset.json
{
    "rrsets":
    [
    {
        "name": "test.example.com.",
        "type": "A",
        "changetype": "REPLACE",
        "ttl": 86400,

        "records":
        [
        {
            "content": "192.168.9.9",
            "disabled": false,
            "name": "test.example.com.",
            "type": "A",
            "priority": 0
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}

# curl -v -X PATCH -H 'X-API-Key: changeme' --data @example_rrset.json http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v1/servers/localhost/zones/example.com.
```